# how to give connection between the drop down list selections and the search button?

Tags: jquery

```
<?php 
include('config.php'); 
$query_parent = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM states") or die("Query failed: ".mysql_error());
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Dependent DropDown List</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#parent_cat").change(function() {
        $(this).after('<div id="loader"><img src="img/loading.gif" alt="loading subcategory" /></div>');
        $.get('loadsubcat.php?parent_cat=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
            $("#sub_cat").html(data);
            $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }); 
    });

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form method="get">
    <label for="category">Select State</label>
    <select name="parent_cat" id="parent_cat">
        <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_parent)): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['state_name']; ?></option>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </select>
    <br/><br/>

    <label>Select District</label>
    <select name="sub_cat" id="sub_cat"></select>


<button type="submit" formaction="demo.php">Search</button>
</form>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

/* /* i have a added a button in my code.. whenever i click it, i want the results to be displayed depending on the selections made using the drop down lists.. but it showing the results irrespective of the selections. how to create a connection between the two? */*/

Comment: Is this file `demo.php`?

Comment: @SridharR sorry, i didn't get you...

Comment: When you choose an option from the list, does it currently do the right thing?

Comment: @Wireblue yup!! it does...

Answer (score 0):

Currently the `sub_cat` is being loaded when the `parent_cat` changes. You just need to adjust your jQuery to load when the button is clicked instead.

First, give the button an ID.

```
<button type="button" id="search_btn">Search</button>
```

Next, tweak the jQuery to detect when the button is clicked.

```
$("#search_btn").click(function(){
// ...
```

As you're using AJAX to handle the loading, submit buttons (and even forms really) are not needed. If you do use submit buttons, make sure you cancel the "submit" event so that the form is not submitted by the browser anyway.

**jQuery API Documentation**
[event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)